# Android How to refactor nested doAsync

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating an app that interacts with SQLite Via Room. Since database operation could not run on the main thread, I do it inside a `doAsync`. Here is my code

```
private fun onItemClick(item:ProductModel){
        //check chart, if not empty add to current chart
        val transaction = Transaction(context!!)
        var transactionModel:TransactionTempModel?
        doAsync {
            var isChartEmpty = transaction.isChartEmpty()
            activity?.runOnUiThread {
                if(isChartEmpty){
                    doAsync {
                        transactionModel=transaction.newTransaction()
                        activity?.runOnUiThread {
                            doAsync {
                                val result = transaction.addToChart(transactionModel!!,item)
                                activity?.runOnUiThread { dialogChartAddition(result) }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    doAsync {
                        transactionModel = transaction.getCurrenTransaction()
                        activity?.runOnUiThread {
                            doAsync {
                                val result=transaction.addToChart(transactionModel!!,item)
                                activity?.runOnUiThread { dialogChartAddition(result) }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

everything is ok but as you see that I do many nested `doAsync` and `runOnUiThread`. Is there any better solution?. I have tried another way this is the only way my app working well.

Comment: You can create a common method for nested doAsync and call it from if & else part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access activity variables in the background/async function, not to need to use `runOnUiThread` for that. Only view or UI related changes have to be on UI thread. I think your code can be simplified to-

```
private fun onItemClick(item:ProductModel) {
    val transaction = Transaction(context!!)
    doAsync {
        var isChartEmpty = transaction.isChartEmpty()
        val transactionModel = 
            if(isChartEmpty) transaction.newTransaction()
            else transaction.getCurrenTransaction()
        val result = transaction.addToChart(transactionModel!!, item)
        activity?.runOnUiThread { dialogChartAddition(result) }
    }  
}
```

You have to check yourself though.